# ionic 3 passing data to popover

Tags: ionic3, ionic-popover

I am unable to make it work. The popup calling code is

```
presentPopover(myEvent){
        //alert('invoke popup')
      let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage, this.data);
      popover.present(
          {
            ev: myEvent
          }
      );
}
```

and the part where i need to access currently is:

```
export class PopoverPage{

  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
   // alert('in the popup')  
   //alert(this.data)
  }
```

So how will the data be avaialbe in the popupover page component ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Parameters/data can be passed to the Popover like this

```
let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage, {key1:value1, key2: value2});
```

And then you can use [`NavParams`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavParams/) to retrieve the data passed to the Popover.

```
    export class PopoverPage{        
      constructor(public navParams:NavParams) {
       console.log(this.navParams.data);
       let value1 = this.navParams.get('key1');
       let value2 = this.navParams.get('key2');
      }
    }
```

For ionic v4, you can send data using [`componentProps`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover#properties) to pass data and retrieve through navParams.

```
const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: PopoverPage,
      componentProps:{key1:value1, key2: value2}
    });
    return await popover.present()
```

Comment: Also, you can get data in popover component and via View Controller, which is a more correct way:

import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

export class PopoverComponent {

  constructor(
    public viewCtrl: ViewController
  ) {}

 // here we are getting data object which we set in parent component
  public data: any= this.viewCtrl.data;
}

Comment: @nikola.maksimovic thats interesting... I will have to check and update.. The [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/ViewController/) doesnt seem to show that property..

Comment: what is method in ionic 4. I got undefined in ionic 4 for this method

Comment: Ya I got it. In ionic 4 there is a property called `componentProps` in `PopoverController`                            
Description:The data to pass to the popover component.
Type          :{ [key: string]: any; }. And we can retrieve it as same as ionic 3, means as `NavParams` @SurajRao

Answer (score 7):

You have to pass ***this.data*** as an ***json*** object, after then you can access the value with key.

Calling popup code:

```
presentPopover(myEvent){
    //alert('invoke popup')
  this.data = {data_key:'your_value'};
  let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage, this.data);
  popover.present(
      {
        ev: myEvent
      }
  );
}
```

Accessing value from popover:

```
export class PopoverPage{
  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController,public navParams:NavParams) {
     // alert('in the popup');
     //alert(this.navParams.get('data_key'));
  }
}
```